# Razor view slow at first load

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm making a website using MVC and Razor.

I have no performace problems, but the first time the view is used the page delay to load.

I believe that is when the view is being compiled.

I read about using other compilers or something. But I'm avoiding dependencies.

Is there any way to compile all views when I start the site, without using other dlls?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674473/pre-compile-razor-views-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: Good, this may be help, but in my case the client wanna edit views.

Comment: you can follow this article hope it helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150237/asp-net-mvc-slow-initial-load

Answer (score -2):

When we change to false, the problem is really minimized.

Into Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

Comment: Bad idea, you shouldn't run in debug mode on production. Better look at pre-compiling javascript / templates instead.

Comment: you are correct @bouke, I change the answer to avoid confusing.
In production pre-compiled updatable views and IIS optimization are used