# ASP.NET MVC - Does PDB files makes site perform slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

We have asp.net mvc website hosted in Azure Web Apps. Everytime we deploy the site takes literally couple of minutes to load. Also I've noticed that site generally performs slow.

When looking at BIN folder, I noticed quiet a lot of PDB files.

Wondering if this PDF files could be causing the performance issue. Any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

PDB files don't affect performance in any way and are only used when debugging.

Comment: Any other reason why web app would take ages to load the first request

Comment: Azure web app deployment might be causing a restart of the web server process. Look at the logs.

Comment: If it's only the first request it's most likely an IIS or architecture issue. In case of the latter we'd need to know what your architecutre look like. Otherwise have a look at these for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis

Answer (score 0):

After a new deploy, the web site is recycled and it takes some time for the .NET runtime to initialize. If this is increasing downtime for you, I would recommend deploying to a slot on the App Service and have auto-swap turned on. You can also choose to have to manually swap the slots.
The purpose of the slot feature, among other things, is to reduce any visibility of the updates to the site by having the initial load time.
Also, ensure that the website settings have Always On set to true.