# slow HTTP Options in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http, http-verbs

does somebody have any information how a HTTP OPTION is handled in ASP.NET.
We use the OPTION to healthcheck our system which is fast (around 1ms) but there are times where the response is too slow (2s) which triggers our healthcheck system. Any idea where to look for the reason? (IIS logs, ASP.NET Events etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which version of ASP.NET. But I would assume it is handled pretty similarly to all other HTTP requests. I think you may be experiencing some issues with a slow [first start request on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis).

Comment: no, first request is not a issue, the healthcheck is send every 2s and the site is on high load.