# .NET Core 3.1, Devart for Oracle, First Call to Database is very slow

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, devart

Hy everybody,

i need Help for the following Problem:

I have a Single-Page-Application (REACT, Webpack) with .NET Core 3.1, Devart for Oracle 9.11.980.

The first call to the Database is very slow (20 Seconds). I tested different Calls from my Single-Page-Application.

1. Call a Rest-API with an connection to a Database. The Response is a JSON-Object. In the DB-Table is only one record. (Duration: 22 Seconds)
2. Call a Rest-API without connection to a Database which is generating the same JSON-Response like the
   Call in Number 1 (Duration: Milliseconds)
3. Call a Rest-API without connection to a Database. The Response is a string (Duration: Milliseconds).

So it seems to be the connection to the Database.

When i restart the App (e.g. F5) the Call of the Rest-API from Number 1 only needs Milliseconds.

When i Stop and Start the AppPool on IIS for that Application, the Rest-API from Number 1 needs again 22 Seconds for the first request.

It is just a simple Call to the Database:

```
             using (Data.ma06kesch_adminModel context = new Data.ma06kesch_adminModel())
            {

                IQueryable<BANKOMATKARTE> query = context.BANKOMATKARTE.ToList();

            }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?
I am not very familiar with IIS. Maybe is it something there? I tried a few different settings but nothing was successful :-/.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "Min Pool Size=0;" in your connection string. If this doesn't help, refer to [Fixing slow initial load for IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis).

In the case of large and complex EF6 model, also look at https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-6-1-code-first-startup-performance/.

Comment: Thank you. Min Pool Size = 0 is not working. I will try the other suggestions.