# Slowness in the first request sent to the IIS

Tags: .net, .net-core, iis

Slowness in the first request sent to the IIS.

Scenario:
When sending the first request to a website in IIS or sending a request after some downtime the response takes much longer than expected.

The following actions have been tried to resolve the issue.

- Set Application Pool Start Mode property to AlwaysRunning
- I compiled as DLLs with Ngen

I identified this problem with code .Net Framework 4.X and .Net Core greater than 2.x WCF and API.

Comment: There are tons of discussions in the past on IIS cold start slowness, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386471/fixing-slow-initial-load-for-iis

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- In IIS Manager, right click on the website, choose "Manage Website" > "Advanced Settings...", make sure that `Preload enabled` is set to **`True`** (the default is `False`).
- In IIS Manager, right click on the application pool, choose "Recycling...", make sure that all options are **unticked**. The default is to always recycle after 1740 minutes (29 hours). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831797(v=ws.11)#recycling-conditions-wizard) for more info.